# Cannot run minimal example of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, bugs

I am using the minimal example provided by many users, to import the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
Hello 
\end{document}
```

Couldn't be any simpler, really. But I am getting the error:

```
Undefined control sequence: \ExplSyntaxOn
Undefined control sequence: \ExplSyntaxOff
```

when compiling with pdfLatex. I am using latest versions of everything. My IDE is TexStudio.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: the library option `all` is adding `minted` for which `shell escape` options are required which may not be enabled in the editor -- using `most` library will overcome this -- see page 11 of the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have an older LaTeX that does not pre-load `expl3`. So you need

```latex
\usepackage{expl3}
```

before

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
```

Comment: Great that worked, thanks! And indeed, my latex installation was old. I did not realize this.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    Hello 
\end{document}
```

OR

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Same issue, same errors

Comment: no problem --go with the answer by @JosephWright