# redefine theorem environment for background shading

Tags: color, environments, backgrounds

I have a pretty long document with lots of theorems. I want to change the styling so that each `theorem` has a lightgray background. I can define a new environment `thm` and then change all `theorem` to `thm`. Is there a (simple) way to just redefine the `theorem` enviroment so that I don't have to change all the `theorem`?

---

I currently have

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray!50}  

...

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

...

\newenvironment{thm}
  {\begin{shaded}\begin{theorem}}
  {\end{theorem}\end{shaded}}
```

---

EDIT: I tried out the tcolorbox as suggested in the comments. I followed

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606420/5870

If I just add `\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}` and do nothing else I get an error

```
 ! Undefined control sequence. \ExplSyntaxOn
```

Somewhere else I found ([Cannot run minimal example of tcolorbox](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588915/cannot-run-minimal-example-of-tcolorbox)) a solution to this which is to load

```
\usepackage{expl3}
```

before tcolorbox. If I add just this and change nothing else I get

```
! Undefined control sequence. \NewDocumentCommand
```

Comment: Stop what you are doing, look at the `tcolorbox` package. It can add backgrounds etc to existing envs (including theorems) in just one line. It is explained in the `tcolorbox` manual.

Comment: @daleif: I attempted this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/606420/5870 and I am getting a bunch of errors. For example  Undefined control sequence. \NewDocumentCommand

Comment: Add your attempt to your example so we can see exactly what you tried. No need to delete the original question

Comment: @daleif: Ok, I tried to explain above what I did.

Comment: Don't just link, show code we can copy without leaving your question. Don't load `expl3` load `xparse`. Seems like you have a very old LaTeX if it does not know `\NewDocumentCommand`, but if you have an old LaTeX then how should `tcolorbox` complain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment. This example runs just fine on a TeXLive 2022 installation

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
breakable,
]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{amsthm}
%\theoremstyle{plain}%
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\tcolorboxenvironment{lem}{
colframe=cyan,
breakable,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt }

\begin{document}

\begin{lem}
  sdfadf
\end{lem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am using MikTeX (I guess I should have said that). I reinstalled MikTeX and now this seems to work.

Comment: @Thomas I almost guessed that. Remember to update miktex (if relevant both in miktex admin and miktex user mode). Then `\NewDocumentCommand` is in the LaTeX kernel, no need for `xparse`